# Getting null value in server side

Tags: jquery

I try to send entire div content to servlet,i get null value

```
var content = $('#Div_id').html();
$.ajax({
type = "POST",
url : url,
data : ({"con" : content})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this serialize()

```
var content = $('#Div_id').serialize();
```

Otherwise use JSON Datatype